# how to insert dynamically added form fields in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, database, forms

I want to add dynamic form fields in the database using PHP. I have used angular to add dynamic form fields. The thing is when I am trying to insert this data into the database only last form field is inserting in the database. SO, I used array and loop to increment and update this form field into the database. but somehow query is not working properly and data is also not inserting into the database. can anybody tell me what is wrong here? I am stuck. Please help. Thanx in advance

```
Php Code:
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_row']))
{
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "midata");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 $camp_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['camp_name']);
 $start_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['start_date']);
 $end_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['end_date']);


$store = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['$store']);
$elements= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['elements']);
$quantity = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);

$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['description']);

for($i=0;$i<count($elements);$i++)
 {
  if( $elements[$i]!="" && $quantity[$i]!="")
  {

$sql = "INSERT INTO create_campaign(camp_name, start_date, end_date,store,elements,quantity, description )
VALUES('$camp_name',' $start_date', '$end_date','$store','$elements[$i]', '$quantity[$i]', '$description')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_query($sql, $link);
}
}
}


?>


HTML Code:
  <div class="row col-md-12" ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                                                    <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" name="records">
                                                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Elements</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Campaign Name" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="elements[]"> 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
                                                           <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme"  name="quantity[]>
                                                             <option value="1">100</option>
                                                             <option value="2">200</option>
                                                             <option value="3">300</option>
                                                             <option value="4">400</option>

                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                     <button type="button" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" ng-click="addNewChoice()" >add</button>
                                                     <button   ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" >Remove</button>
                                                     </fieldset>  
                                                </div>   
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="description">
                                      </div>
                                        <input class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit_row">

                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

Comment: In the html, quantity name property is not closed properly. Also single inputs like text and select should not be an array, since they only hold one value.

Comment: If I can not use it as an array then, how can I use it? I want to add multiple fields.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I do? I tried changing input attribute to multiple but didn't work

Comment: @Mouser: Please reply man. I need help

Comment: Please update your question with how you are trying to get multiple values in your field + an error message from the database would be nice.

Comment: first, i am not getting any errors. See, I have added input fields dynamically. On clicking add button fields will get added. But while inserting that value into the database it is taking only last fields value. For example, i have 2 form fields 1.Element 2. Quantity. On clicking add button 2 more element and quantity fields will get add. but only last element and quantity field is inserting into DB. What do I do?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable like x=1 and use it inside your array of input like name="input_name[+ x +]"
and increment the variable after each input field i.e x++
You can access those inputs using inputName[1], input_name[2] in your php controller